# Web scraping issue with selenium / Get comments

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been trying to perform some web scraping from Dealabs website.

Here is the example page :

https://www.dealabs.com/bons-plans/saneo-climatiseur-2166879

The main goal was to be able to get all comments and print them.

Sample code below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = "https://www.dealabs.com/bons-plans/saneo-climatiseur-2166879"

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(url)

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]/span"))
)
button.click()

comments_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("commentList")
comments = comments_list.find_elements_by_class_name("commentList-item")

for comment in comments:
    _id = comment.get_attribute("id")
    author = comment.find_element_by_class_name('userInfo-username').text
    content = comment.find_element_by_class_name('userHtml-content').text
    timestamp = comment.find_element_by_class_name('text--color-greyShade').text
    print(_id)
    print(author)
    print(content)
    print(timestamp)
    print('-' * 30)

driver.close()
```

Fact is by doing this I'm only able to collect the most rated comments, not all.

I am kinda confused.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you would need to click on next page and grab the items

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the comments by sending a `page` parameter as

```
https://www.dealabs.com/bons-plans/saneo-climatiseur-2166879?page=1
https://www.dealabs.com/bons-plans/saneo-climatiseur-2166879?page=2
https://www.dealabs.com/bons-plans/saneo-climatiseur-2166879?page=3
```

and so on instead of clicking the next button each time.

Comment: it shows the same content with all 3 URLs, and you have not provided a way for web scraping

Comment: There are two comment sections on the page. One for the top comments (that you see the same content) and the other section is paginated comments under the top comments. Since the goal is to get all of them, second section should work, and the way he gets the comments looks fine. Just need to go through the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks everyone for your time.

I figured the issue.

Edited 2 lines:

```
comments_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("anchorTarget")
comments = comments_list.find_elements_by_class_name("commentList-item")
```

I was not focusing the correct part of the html. That's why I was only getting the top comments.

Thanks again.